# Windows 11 crashing at startup with BSOD. Unable to get option to repair with Windows 11 ISO

Tags: windows-11, bsod

I had a normal working Windows 11 installation. Overtime I don't know why, many shortcuts on the desktop became non-working. But Edge browser was still working so I didn't notice it as a system problem. But a month ago Windows 11 stopped working, I tried to restart but it is showing me a critical process had died BSOD error.

So far I tried flashing a pen drive with Windows 11 ISO and booting with it, I tried to repair, but I'm not getting any option to repair, it is giving me option to repair upgrade which will remove all the file settings and installed programs. I have important login information stored on Edge and Firefox.

Is there a way to repair this system and getting it back to working condition? I suspect some system files have become corrupted, while it was working I tried sfc/scannow and DISM upgrade but DISM restorehealth failed due to lack of source files, even when I correctly mentioned them.

Answer (score 1):

> So far I tried flashing a pen drive with Windows 11 ISO and booting
> with it, I tried to repair, but I'm not getting any option to repair,

This occurs because Windows is not running. Repair Install has always (many years) required Windows to be running to work.

> It is giving me option to repair upgrade which will remove all the
> file settings and installed programs.

That is all Windows can do when not running - normal response in this situation.

Way forward:

Recover your files (a) boot USB to see drive and copy to another USB disk  or (b) remove the drive and get files that way.  Recovery depends on the condition of the main disk.

Once the back up has been secured,  get the manufacturer's disk test App and test the drive - it may have errors.

Then when ready, install Windows fresh and recover your data.

Comment: After installing a new Windows, how do I recover the data? Can I copy the system files of the new installation on to the corrupted Windows 11?

Comment: You must recover data BEFORE installing Windows.   I gave you 2 methods. If you reinstalled Windows first I am not sure what you can recover.  See if there a Windows.old file.

Comment: @linuxtroubleshooting - You don’t. Based on what you described your storage device failed.

Comment: @Ramhound That is a new SSD, I didn't even use it for 3 months.

Comment: @linuxtroubleshooting - That wasn’t made clear in the question, but regardless, working storage devices don’t have broken desktop shortcuts. When CANNOT be repaired outside of Windows. If Windows cannot boot you can’t perform an in-place repair